# Python compare 2 lists filled with 3-tuples

Tags: python, list, compare, tuples

I have 2 lists each filled with the 3-tuples.

In the beginning they will be equal:

```
a = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
b = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
```

**Case 1:**

An extra element is added to `b` at the end

```
a = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
b = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123),(3,1,123)]

Return: Added (3,1,123)
```

**Case 2**

Element 2 in `b` changes from `124` -> `123`

```
a = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
b = [(1,1,123),(1,2,123),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]

Return: Changed a[1] to (1,2,123)
```

**Case 3**

A combination of Case 1 and 2, an extra element is added to `b` and element 2 in `b` changes from `124` -> `123`

```
a = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
b = [(1,1,123),(1,2,123),(2,1,231),(2,2,123),(3,1,123)]

Return: Added (3,1,123) and Changed a[1] to (1,2,123)
```

In all the cases `a==b` returns False, what I'm trying to do is figure out how to compare the lists and find whether an element was added, changed, or both.  Looking for any suggestions.

Comment: if when `a==b` you can return false can you return true for all other conditions or when `a!=b`? Or does it has to be when an element was added, changed, or both

Comment: Has to been when an element is added, changed, or both.  And when it is one of those 3 cases what was changed, added, or both.  Edited to what I'm looking to return in all the cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
changed = False
added = len(tuple1) != len(tuple2)
for e1, e2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2):
    if e1 != e2:
        changed = True
return changed, added, a==b
```

This is before the edit. This will check to see if added, changed, or the same and return three booleans accordingly.

```
tuple1 = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,123)]
tuple2 = [(1,1,123),(1,2,124),(2,1,231),(2,2,13), (0,0)]
changed = False
info = ""
if len(tuple1) != len(tuple2):
    info += "Added " + str(tuple2[-1])
for e1, e2 in zip(tuple1, tuple2):
    if e1 != e2:
        info += " Changed a[" + str(tuple2.index(e2)) + "] to " + str(e2)
print(info)
```

prints ---> "Added (0, 0) Changed a[3] to (2, 2, 13)"

The above code is post edit and will work in any instance where only one element is added and the element is added to the second to tuple or "b".

Comment: Thats perfect, gets me what I'm looking for and on my way!

Answer (score 1):

```
added = len(b) > len(a)
changed = b[:len(a)] != a
both = added and changed
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare if `len(b) > len(b)` to check if an element was added or not, and if `False`, then compare if `a==b` or not.

```
if len(b) > len(a):
    if b[:len(a)] == a:
        print 'Added only'
    else:
        print 'Added and changed'
else:
    if b != a:
        print 'Changed'
    else:
        print 'No changes'
```

Answer (score -2):

List is a [mutable sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable), when comparing lists, it won't actually compare it's contents.

However, tuple, is immutable. comparing tuples will give you expected behavior in your case.

```
tuple(a) == tuple(b)
```

It's a simple way to test whether a == b.